Display adjacent Java Swing Polygons without gap even when using antialiasing
Using antialiasing in filling adjacent polygons in Java Swing can result in a fine gap between the polygons. The gap can be closed when using drawPolygon in addition to fillPolygon, but the polygon is drawn/filled twice and takes more than twice the time to just fill it.
Is there a way to get rid of the gap with just fillPolygon?
Here is some code to illustrate the behaviour:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class PolygonGap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();

        Polygon p1 = new Polygon();
        p1.addPoint(66, 210); p1.addPoint(70, 128); p1.addPoint(160, 152); p1.addPoint(159, 233);


        Polygon p2 = new Polygon();
        p2.addPoint(159, 233); p2.addPoint(160, 152); p2.addPoint(246, 175); p2.addPoint(247, 255);


        Polygon p3 = new Polygon();
        p3.addPoint(70, 128); p3.addPoint(74, 52); p3.addPoint(161, 76); p3.addPoint(160, 152);


        Polygon p4 = new Polygon();
        p4.addPoint(160, 152); p4.addPoint(161, 76); p4.addPoint(245, 99); p4.addPoint(246, 175);


        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

//        g2.setColor(Color.black);
//        g2.drawPolygon(p1); g2.drawPolygon(p2); g2.drawPolygon(p3); g2.drawPolygon(p4);
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.fillPolygon(p1); g2.fillPolygon(p2); g2.fillPolygon(p3); g2.fillPolygon(p4);
        g2.dispose();

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
    }
}

Uncomment the drawPolygon lines to see the gap vanish.
This code is only for demo purposes. In the original code all polygons may have a different color from each other.
Here the view with the gap:

A possible solution would be to add one pixel to the right and lower coordinate, so that they would overlap by one pixel. While working, it feels a bit dirty and comes with other consequences as it is part of a larger project where complex surfaces are computed and adding one pixel to the right and the bottom is mathematically more complex.
I also tried to translate(0.5, 0.5) (mentioned elsewhere on SO), but it didn't help.

The documentation of Graphics clarifies this nicely.  Read the paragraph that starts with “Coordinates are infinitely thin” and the list immediately following it, which is introduced with “The graphics pen hangs down and to the right from the path it traverses.”

I am aware of the specs. The problem arises from the fact that 'infinetly thin' is actually not infintely thin but clearly visible when antialiasing.

Still not sure why using fillPolygon(...) and drawPolygon(...) would more than double the painting time and why that would be an issue. Maybe you do the drawing once to a BufferedImage and then create a second BufferedImage with the final result so you don't continually paint the polygons.

I don't understand your uncertainty. Filling and drawing a polygon each take a certain amount of time. In my case, drawing takes slightly longer than filling. Hence, when I draw and fill a polygon, it takes slightly more than double the time compared to when I just fill the polygon.

I’ve tried all sorts of approaches, without success.  Will your performance suffer noticeably if you use both draw and fill?  I mean, consider how many graphics operations occur per second in a modern videogame.

The application uses around 500 polygons and with just filling I get 35 fps and if I add drawing it drops to 15 fps. If on the other hand I switch antialiasing off I get 150 fps. Maybe I'll do without anitaliasing in general and use it just where absolutely necessary.


but the polygon is drawn/filled twice and takes more than twice the time to just fill it.

Not sure why painting would be double.
Maybe you can use an Area for the painting:
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class PolygonGap2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();

        Polygon p1 = new Polygon();
        p1.addPoint(66, 210); p1.addPoint(70, 128); p1.addPoint(160, 152); p1.addPoint(159, 233);


        Polygon p2 = new Polygon();
        p2.addPoint(159, 233); p2.addPoint(160, 152); p2.addPoint(246, 175); p2.addPoint(247, 255);


        Polygon p3 = new Polygon();
        p3.addPoint(70, 128); p3.addPoint(74, 52); p3.addPoint(161, 76); p3.addPoint(160, 152);


        Polygon p4 = new Polygon();
        p4.addPoint(160, 152); p4.addPoint(161, 76); p4.addPoint(245, 99); p4.addPoint(246, 175);


        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

        Area area = new Area();
        area.add(new Area(p1));
        area.add(new Area(p2));
        area.add(new Area(p3));
        area.add(new Area(p4));

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fill(area);

        g2.dispose();

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
    }
}

I can't measure the speed, so I don't know if it is any faster.

I just edited my question. The polygons in the original code do not have the same color. Otherwise, I could just draw one big polygon instead of 4 small ones and would get rid of the problem.
